# Can you use the result of a count in another formula

Tags: sql, count, multiplication

```
SELECT DISTINCT Course_NO, count(section_ID) Sections
FROM SECTION
group by course_No
having count(section_id) > 3;
```

I need to use the values of count(section_id) to determine the total capacity by mulitiplying each value x the capacity for each section.

Comment: what do you want to multiply the count(section_ID) with? what is capacity for each section? another column?

Comment: Can you elaborate further, what field will you be joining on - give an example with data if possible.

Comment: if I have a total of 4 sections, and each section has a capacity of 30, I need to multiply 4 * 30. I determined the 4 sections using the count in oracle

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a "with" statement?

```
;with SampleData as 
(
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Course_NO, 
    COUNT(section_ID) Sections 
    FROM SECTION 
    GROUP BY course_No 
    HAVING COUNT(section_id) > 3
)
SELECT * FROM SampleData
```

This will allow you to easily re-use those counts.

Comment: What is before the ; in the first line?

Comment: I'm not see how to reuse the count values. sorry, new

Comment: Semi-colon not necessary, sorry.  

From here you could do "SELECT Course_No, Sections * 30 FROM SampleData"

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use DISTINCT when grouping, your query will work fine with it.

```
SELECT
    Course_NO
    , COUNT(section_ID) Sections
FROM
    SECTION
GROUP BY
    course_No
HAVING
    COUNT(section_id) > 3;
```

Now, to use the COUNT() value, from what I've understood - you want the product of course_NO times the occurrence of section_ID for all the section_ID occurring more than 3 times. You already have the COUNT from your own query, simply display another column with the product:

```
SELECT
    Course_NO
    , COUNT(section_ID) [Sections]
    , Course_NO * COUNT(section_ID) [Capacity]
FROM
    SECTION
GROUP BY
    course_No
HAVING
    COUNT(section_id) > 3;
```

Or if you have a fixed number that you want to multiply with the count, replace course_NO in the capacity column with that value (the second query above)